# Looking for a good Web Server that is cheap

Tags: web-server

I am a Project Manager, and former Lead Developer for a software portal system that requires a forum software to run.  I am in need of a server that is cheap, reliable, and supports the latest PHP (5.2+), MySQL, unlimited e-mails (preferably), a cPanel, multiple sub-domains (atleast 3+).

Currently I am paying $34.95 USD/month (approx. $420 USD/year).  This is too high for me to pay to keep the site running.  I just recently became Project Manager and in charge of Finances and I'm extremely concerned for the future of [Dream Portal](http://dream-portal.net).  With those prices I'm not sure I'll be able to keep it running for too long.

Can someone please tell me of a good server that meets all of the requirements that I listed above that is cheaper on a yearly basis?

Note: Currently on a Dedicated Server with limited disk space at 15000 MB (15 GB), monthly bandwidth = 500000 MB, 50 emails limit, 20 sub-domains limit, 30 FTP accts., and 25 SQL Databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluehost is priced at around $6.95/month and has everything you need:

http://www.bluehost.com/

Dreamhost costs slightly more but also offers SSH access.  They run PHP 5 but am not sure if it's PHP 5.2+.

http://www.dreamhost.com/

**Disclaimer:**  I am an affiliate, and I have worked with clients using Dreamhost.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching at sites like [Lowendbox](http://www.lowendbox.com)? They are a forum that mainly specialises in sub-$7 VPSes and also some dedicated servers. There are many offers there and sometimes some discount codes as well. I have used them to find deals and offers when I need a machine.

Comment: What does lowend mean exactly?  Doesn't sound good to me, IMO.

Comment: From my experience - quality varies. Some are good some are not. However, since it's cheap, it is easy to throw away if it is not good. Most of them allow monthly payments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [site5](http://www.site5.com/)?  I've been using them for a few years... No cPanel on normal accounts but I couldn't be happier

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with umbrahosting.com 
http://umbrahosting.com/
cPanel on shared, vps or dedicated servers and I think they meet your requirements.